# Rails 5.1 - Submit form via ajax, returned javascript not executing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 5.1 form for creating a user object, which looks like this when rendered:

```
<form class="upload-form" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">

<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

...all the fields...

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" data-disable-with="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

It submits fine, and the controller actions fires. Here it is:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|      
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

But the create.js.erb which is returned does not execute in the browser:

```
$('#upload-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
  var field = $('#upload-form').find('input[name=fileinput]');
  var file = field[0].files[0];
  console.log(file);
});
```

I am confused as to why this js does not get executed (I can see it returned in the response).

Comment: probably the name of js file should be create.js.erb

Comment: it is called create.js.erb. Question updated

Comment: You appear to be targeting a form with an ID of `upload-form`, but your form has a *class* of `upload-form`...

Comment: Omg, well spotted. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `upload-form` as a `class`, but you are calling it as a `ID` in the *JS*

Change

```
$('#upload-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
  var field = $('#upload-form').find('input[name=fileinput]');
  var file = field[0].files[0];
  console.log(file);
});
```

to this

```
$('.upload-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
  var field = $('.upload-form').find('input[name=fileinput]');
  var file = field[0].files[0];
  console.log(file);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else tripping across this issue, but the above doesn't help:

I am using CoffeeScript and ran into this same issue.  I had a file called index.coffee which would render a partial template into a function to replace a div on the client side. Worked GREAT when I was calling a route the normal way, but would not work when I was rendering it via a "button_to".

Rails was rendering the JS properly, sending it down to the browser, and I could test the JS and it worked fine.  But it would not be invoked on the button_to click.

All I did was rename the file to "index.js.coffee" and it started working. Yay, Rails weirdness!